# Ensuring no duplicate and empty variables in database entries

Tags: php

I have an array with data to be inserted into a table through a loop. Where each array item is to be inserted as a row.. I need to check if the array item eg array[1] exist in the table and if array[1] is empty it should not insert but if its not in the table and not empty it should insert. Below is my effort. but its not working. Pls someone help me

```
$array = ['', 'Albert', '', 'Thomas', 'Alice', 'Godwin', '', 'Jonas'];
$arraySize = sizeof($array);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $arraySize; $x++) {
    $catName = $array[$x];
    $checkAvailability = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT catName FROM table WHERE catName LIKE'$catName'")) OR DIE(mysql_error());
    if (!empty($catName)) {
        if ($checkAvailability < 1) {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(catName) VALUES ('$catName')") OR DIE(mysql_error());
            echo $catName . " Inserted <br/>";
        } elseif ($checkAvailability > 0) {
            echo $catName . " Exist";
        }
    } else {
        echo "$catName Is Empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Need space between like and value at `LIKE'$catName'` and is `table` is your table name or its just for demo purpose to show here??

Comment: *"not working"* - so what did `mysql_error()` have to say about that?

Comment: use mysqli functions instead of mysql.

Comment: I think "OR DIE(mysql_error()); " can be removed from the queries

Comment: mysyql_error() says nothing, No error. LIKE'$catName' works fine with no space when i take the duplicate checking code off and use only !empty($catName). It is the duplicate checking code that is giving me the problems

Comment: @jophab thank you **or die(mysql_error())** at the check availability code was the problem'. Thank you very much. You guys are God sent. I have been working on this since last night. Just couldn't figure what was wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

"or die(mysql_error())" at the check availability code is the problem